# How to call a variable in another method?

Tags: java

How to call a variable in another `method` in the same `class`?

```
public void example(){    
    String x='name';
}

public void take(){
    /*how to call x variable*/
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First declare your method to accept a parameter:

```
public void take(String s){
    // 
}
```

Then pass it:

```
public void example(){
    String x = "name";
    take(x);
}
```

---

Using an instance variable is not a good choice, because it would require calling some code to set up the value *before* `take()` is called, and `take()` have no control over that, which could lead to bugs. Also it wouldn't be threadsafe.

Comment: I can't agree that it is "not a good choice."  The OP is already faced with a situation where "`x` is already being set up," and which would not be thread-safe (if more than one thread was trying to access it).  This is the design that he has, and he makes no mention of threads in his post.  Instance variables *would* solve the problem he described.

Answer (score 6):

You make it an instance variable of the class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    String x;

    public void example(){ x = "name"; } // note the double quotes
    public void take(){ System.out.println( x ); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since they are in different scopes you can't.

One way to get around this is to make x a member variable like so:

```
String x;

public void example(){
    this.x = "name";
}

public void take(){
    // Do stuff to this.x
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Test
{

static String x;
public static void method1
{
x="name";
}

public static void method2
{

System.out.println(+x);

}

}
```

Comment: Rather than just posting a code snippet, can you explain (in words) _why_ this answers the OPs question? This would improve your answer a lot.