# How can i access variable of one method into another?

Tags: java

I am creating android application. I have created one method `testMethod1()` then I have created another method `testMethod2()`. i have declare object of class in `testMethod1()`. How can i access object `obj` in `testMethod2()` ?

```
Public class TestClass() {

    public void testMethod1() {
        final ModalClass obj = new ModalClass();
        testMethod2();
    }

    public void testMethod2() {
        //I want to access 'obj' here
    }
}
```

**Edited quetion**

I have created modal for listview. i want to set data into listview as bellow. but i can not be able to access `locationDet` into another method. its displaying `can not resolve symbol 'locationDet'`.

```
 Public class TestClass() {
 private List<LocationDetailModel> LocationDetailList = new 
 ArrayList<LocationDetailModel>();

 public void testMethod1() {

  JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");
  for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

  final LocationDetailModel locationDet = new LocationDetailModel();
  locationDet.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
            testMethod2();
  LocationDetailList.add(locationDet);
  }

 }

  public void testMethod2() {
            //I want to access 'obj' here

         locationDet.setRating(results.getInt("rating"));
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you send it to the other function? Or declare it in the TestClass instead of the function itself?

Comment: Two ways: Either pass obj as parameter to testMethod2(), if  this is the only method need var OR create obj as class level variable so that all methods have access to this variable.

Comment: why don't you try passing as `argument` to `testMethod2(obj)` ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling variable in another method (JAVA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918414/calling-variable-in-another-method-java)

Comment: I have edited quetion.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:
1. You make the Variavble class known like this:

```
       Public class TestClass(){

             final ModalClass var = new ModalClass();

                public void testMethod1() {

                 var = new ModalClass();
                    testMethod2();
              }

              public void testMethod2() {
                    //I want to access 'var' here
          } 
}
```

or you give your Var to test methode2 like this:

```
Public class TestClass()
{
    public void testMethod1() {

    final ModalClass var = new ModalClass();
        testMethod2(var);
    }

    public void testMethod2(ModalClass var) {
        //I want to access 'var' here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `ModalClass var` as a private attribute:

```
Public class TestClass(){

  private final ModalClass var;
  public void testMethod1() {

  this.var = new ModalClass();
      testMethod2();
  }

  public void testMethod2() {
    //I want to access 'var' here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variables which are in scope and are visible. In your case you have a `local` variable which you wish to use in another method.

1. You can pass it as a method parameter. For this you will need to modify the signature of the method as below

   ```
   public void testMethod2( LocationDetailModel locationModelDet ){
        // now you acess the locationModelDet
   }
   ```

and you can pass `locationDet` as parameter to the `testMethod2` as `testMethod(locationDet)`

2. Another alternate option is instead of using local variable you may create a instance variable as

   ```
    private LocationDetailModel locationDet = new LocationDetailModel();
   ```

Now in `testMethod1()` you need not create a local variable you can simply just set the `title`. For this you need not modify the signature of your `testMethid2()`. You will be able to acess the `locationDet` in both the method.