# JButton in Eclipse: "Button cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton

New to Java and this Page.
I am trying to perfom a certain action when a JButton is pressed. Following this tutorial (in German, sorry) http://www.java-tutorial.org/actionlistener.html, I used the JFrame Design feature and added content afterwards:

```
public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public JFrame()
{

    this.setTitle("BMS Anpassen");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnFlush = new JButton("Flush!");
    btnFlush.setBounds(170, 209, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnFlush);

    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    spinner.setToolTipText("Gib die Spannung ein!");
    spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(new Float(3000), new Float(2700), new Float(4100), new Float(100)));
    spinner.setBounds(56, 49, 52, 20);
    contentPane.add(spinner);

    JLabel lblMv = new JLabel("mV");
    lblMv.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    lblMv.setBounds(113, 51, 24, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblMv);

    JButton btnSetParameters = new JButton("Set Parameters");
    btnSetParameters.setBounds(152, 175, 130, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnSetParameters);

    //Buttons dem Listener zuordnen
    btnFlush.addActionListener(this);
    btnSetParameters.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

    if(ae.getSource() == this.btnSetParameters){

    // Parameter in Config schreiben/Write parameters in Config
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("ConfigBMS.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    bw.write("25000");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("42000");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("27000");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("41000");

    bw.close();
    }
    else
    {           
    }
}

}
```

It now gives me the errormessage "btnSetParameters cannot be resolved or is not a field". Reading through other posts on JButtons here didn't help me or I didn't understand it. I feel like the `this` in `if(ae.getSource() == this.btnSetParameters){` is the problem, but I can't find a way to fix it.

Any push in the right direction is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance,

Oli

Comment: In which line does the error appear? :)

Comment: Declare `btnSetParameters` outside of the constructor as you did with `contentPane`.

Comment: Please don't upvote badly researched questions. Just because OP pretends to be new, it doesn't mean he's also unable to write a few words into Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling variable in another method (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918414/calling-variable-in-another-method-java)

Comment: I got thrown into coding and don't have time to learn it from the ground up, so googling is way harder for me than it might be for some of you. With also english not being my first language, you often just don't know what you are looking for. But thanks for the link, i will try to understand that. so far crazyname-guys answer below works! Edit: Error appeared in line `if(ae.getSource() == this.btnSetParameters){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an scope issue, btnSetParameters must be declared as a Frame member field

```
public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton btnSetParameters;
```

and no inside the constructor, use the constructor instead to initialize the button!

```
public JFrame() {
    .... 
    btnSetParameters = new JButton("Set Parameters");
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that helped. I had to build try/catch blocks for the writing in the configfile-part, but so far it works!

Comment: and `public class JFrame`, hmmm carefully with it should be - `public class MyFrame`, don't to use reserved java name or identifier from methods, constructors

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the the JButton `btnSetParameters` a field of the class - currently it's just in the context of the constructor.